# Auto hyperlink Jira Issues in Git commits in SourceTree

Tags: git, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, issue-tracking

Jira will automatically scan a git repo and pull in commits that are tagged with a Jira ID (ie `QA-244`).

Is there a way to display the links to Jira issues from with SourceTree:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Information on setting this up can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/danielcosta/5620616)

Basically just set up text replacement for all your project abbreviations with the URL that they point to. My windows version was a little different than documented there and went like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

To make the commit text in SourceTree link to a **GitHub Issue** or **Bitbucket Issue** (standard issue tracker, similar to Jira), where the Issue is in the form "#1234", use this approach:

1. Open your repository window
2. Click **'Settings'** in the toolbar
3. Click **'Advanced'**
4. In the **'Commit Text Replacements'** section, click **'Add'**
5. For the **Replacement Type**, select **'Other'**
6. In the **'Regex Pattern'** field, enter `#(\d+)($|[^a-zA-Z0-9-])` (but see the Note below)
7. In the **'Replace With'** field:

   - a. On Mac OS X, enter `<a href="https://bitbucket.org/your_username/your_project/issue/$1/">#$1</a>$2` (make sure you include the speech marks)
   - b. On Windows, enter `https://bitbucket.org/your_username/your_project/issue/$1`
8. Click OK twice
9. Re-select the commit log item which has a mention of the #12345 style issue number. It should now show a clickable hyperlink to the issue, which will open your web browser.

**Note:** For step 6, you may consider using a regex like `#(\d{1,4})($|[^a-zA-Z0-9-])` to prevent matching URLs that have `"#numbers"` in them, like `www.example.com/#123456` - More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377897/help-with-regex-need-up-to-3-number-after-the-dot)

**Sources:**

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/link-to-bitbucket-issue-tracker-from-commits-296911608.html
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/237742/sourcetree-what-format-is-link-to-url-for-commit-text-links

---

**Apply the same links in JetBrains products**

You can also have the same links in IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio, PyCharm, etc, when viewing the **"Version Control"** tab for Git history:

IDE -> Preferences -> Search for "Issue Navigation" -> Add -> Enter regular the same expression and hyperlink. More info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/add-issue-navigation-link-dialog.html).